# Random array sorting (1,000,000)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random

I've been working on this problem:

Create an array of 10 random integers, and array of 1,000 random integers, and an array of a million (1,000,000) random integers.
For each array:
Display the first ten elements of the array.
Call selection sort for the array. 
Display the first ten elements of the sorted array.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class Lab_10_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myRandomArray1[] = new int[10];

        int myRandomArray2[] = new int[1000];

        int myRandomArray3[] = new int[1000000];

        count(myRandomArray1);
        printOriginal(myRandomArray1);
        selectionSort(myRandomArray1);
        printArray(myRandomArray1);

        count(myRandomArray2);
        printOriginal(myRandomArray2);
        selectionSort(myRandomArray2);
        printArray(myRandomArray2);

        count(myRandomArray3);
        printOriginal(myRandomArray3);
        selectionSort(myRandomArray3);
        printArray(myRandomArray3);

    }

    public static void count(int[] value) {
        System.out.println("The original order is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            value[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }

    }

    public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
        int startScan, index, minIndex, minValue;
        for (startScan = 0; startScan < (array.length - 1); startScan++) {
            minIndex = startScan;
            minValue = array[startScan];
            for (index = startScan + 1; index < array.length; index++) {
                if (array[index] < minValue) {
                    minValue = array[index];
                    minIndex = index;
                }
            }
            array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
            array[startScan] = minValue;
        }

    }

    public static void printArray(int[] value) {
        System.out.println("The sorted values are:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.print(value[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printOriginal(int[] value) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.println(value[j]);
        }

    }

}
```

For some reason my randomArray3 (1,000,000) won't print it's sorted values, and I can't figure out why...(I'm still very new to Java, and I really want to know how and why this isn't working, so I can correct myself and learn.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is it that it "won't print"? Does the program crash? Do you get a stack trace? Or does it simply fail silently?

Comment: It's not that it won't print. Your sort is slow and takes a long time. Put some logging statements around to verify.

Comment: Selection sort is O(n^2), so it's more likely that the program will just take a reeeeally long time to run 1,000,000,000,000 operations. My suggestion: don't use selection sort, but if you need to for some kind of school assignment, don't make it sort a million items.

Comment: You're only inserting ten values into your arrays! Everything else is `0`. And `count` is a terrible name for that method.

Comment: to selection sort 1000 times more items you need 1000000 times more time

Comment: A side note on defining method, your `printArray` and `printOriginal` differs just by a print statement. To note further when you execute your program you should see the original order of `myRandomArray3` and then the program takes time.

Comment: **and an array of a million (1,000,000) random integers**, it's not true, for your `count` method you just initialize previous 10 variables, so your sort length should be **10**

Comment: Hint: details matter. It is a huge difference if you do all work on the first 10 entries of an array, or if you do it for all members using array.length

Comment: Given that this looks like homework, it seems more likely the actual answer you're expected to come up with is doing only 10 iterations of selection sort. Which would complete in reasonable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code, I think the problem is just that running an O(n^2) selection sort on a million integers takes a really long time. The program takes forever to terminate.

Replacing your sorting algorithm with the built-in (and very efficient) `Arrays.sort`, the program terminates almost immediately:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Lab_10_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ...

        count(myRandomArray3);
        printOriginal(myRandomArray3);
        Arrays.sort(myRandomArray3);
        printArray(myRandomArray3);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Probably not forever. Maybe a few months.

Comment: The problem statement specifically mentions selection sort. However, I'm wondering if the goal instead is to display the 10 smallest elements and use quick select (instead of select sort), which should be ok for random data. Then again, if only the 10 smallest elements need to be sorted, this could be done with an working array of 10 elements and a single pass over the large array.

Comment: @rcgldr or you can iteration-limit selection sort. Which would make sense as an exercise, if they made you do something like implement selection sort in a previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Selection sort complexity is O(n^2).
It means that in the worst case it may take up to (constant * 1_000_000^2) operations to sort 1_000_000 numbers. And this is a huge number.
`selectionSort(myRandomArray3);` simply doesn't terminate quickly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insertion sort is usually better than Selection sort for short arrays.
2. For large arrays use Quicksort, Heapsort or Merge Sort.

Learning how to program those methods is useful.